# Block POST PUT and DELETE but allow GET from specific referrer

Tags: nginx, web-server, http, requests

I'm using nginx and I want to block post, put and delete requests when they come from an unknown referrer.

Meaning, I have the referrer: "*.example.com" and from this referrer I want to allow all GET, PUT and POST (yeah, I know thats easy to fake the referrer ...), if "*.example.com" is not the referrer only GET should be allowed.

All the solutions I came with don't work ...

I would like to have this on the server block to make everything clean (I use a very big file with all the locations).

My first approach was:

> limit_except none block server_names *.example.com {
>      if ($http_request != GET) {
>         deny all;
>   }

But, I cannot nest an if ...

Then, I tried this:

> map $http_referer $allow_referer {
>          default                 0;
>          "~example.com"          1;
>   }
>   map $allow_referer $disallow_referer {
>      0       1;
>      1       "";
>   }
>
> location ... {
>   ...
>   if ($invalid_referer) {
>          limit_except GET {
>                  deny all;
>          }
>   }
>   }

Same as above.
Then, I used a config file I found on the web with some modifications :

> set $cors '';
>
> if ($http_origin ~* (https?://.*.example.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {
>      set $cors "true";
>   }
>
> if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
>      set $cors "${cors}options";
>   }
>
> if ($request_method = 'GET') {
>      set $cors "${cors}get";
>   }
>
> if ($request_method = 'POST') {
>      set $cors "${cors}post";
>   }
>
> if ($request_method = 'PUT') {
>      set $cors "${cors}put";
>   }
>
> if ($request_method = 'DELETE') {
>      set $cors "${cors}delete";
>   }
>
> if ($cors = "trueget") {
>      return 200;
>   }
>
> if ($cors = "truepost") {
>      return 403;
>   }
>
> if ($cors = "trueput") {
>     return 403;
>   }
>
> if ($cors = "truedelete") {
>     return 403;
>   }

Seems very clean but didn't work.

Is there any way to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the server block and it works:

```
add_header Allow "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD" always;
valid_referers none blocked server_names *.example.com;

if ($request_method !~ ^(GET)$ ) {
    set $req A;
    }

if ($invalid_referer) {
    set $ref "${req}A";
    }

  if ($ref = AA) {
   return 403;
   }
```

Comment: [If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)